# How to get response from FORM action in php

Tags: php, html, forms, box-api

I am trying to create a html file in php where in user has to upload data for uploading in Box.net using API.
Form tag's action attribute has a url, which sends back an acknowledgement message.

My problem is when i upload a file and click submit,I get an xml response page.
But i don't want User to see such data,
but i want this data for computation and show user appropriate message.

How can i get that xml response?

Following is my code:

```
<?php
$upload_url = 'https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload/i9g1fmnn9odhg739sdgdfgdg/480416060';
?>

<form action="<?php echo $upload_url;?>"
 enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">
<input type="file" name="new_file1" />
<input type="text" name="share" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="upload_files" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload the file.
2. Read the file's data.
3. Send the file's data to the URL in question using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: how can i sent those values(file object) in curl.Can you please give some code examples as i am a beginner in php

Answer (score 1):

you can do that

```
echo $_POST['new_file1']
echo $_POST['share']
echo $_POST['upload_files']
```

Answer (score 0):

To send your request to Box you'll need to change the form so that it posts to your own PHP file.  Then to send the request to box from your server, in the file that you directed the form to submit to you'd do something like the following:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

$upload_url = 'https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload/i9g1fmnn9odhg739sdgdfgdg/480416060';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
    "file_box" => "@" . $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'],
    "share"    => $_POST['share']
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 

$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

The $response object will contain the response from Box.

Comment: When a file is uploaded to PHP it processes the request and places the file(s) into a global array called $_FILES.  'upload' accesses the uploaded file, and 'tmp_name' gets the temporary location on the server where the file has been stored.